# Redirecting to home-page when saving any edited code

Tags: redirect, homepage

Whenever I edit any theme code in my Dashboard -> Appearance -> Editor and try to save it, the file is not saved and it automatically redirects me to the homepage.

I don't know why is this happening. I cleared the cache through the W3-Total Cache plugin.

A few hours before I did the same process, it was working perfectly.

But now, I can't tell what the problem is.

I also tried the same process in a different browser: the result is the same.

I'm using the latest version of WordPress (Version 3.0.4).

Comment: Are you using the redirection plugin?  What other plugins are installed?

Comment: @Chris_O I was not using any redirection plugin, but after changing the name of 3 pages, this is happening, I tried the solution provided by @Jonnybojangles but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced an issue similar to this several months ago.  I was using a plugin to kill query strings from the URL for SEO purposes.  Long story short the plugin was killing search pages and admin pages as well.

As Chris_O mentioned the redirection plugin I encountered a similar redirection issue when track modify posts is enabled.

The plugin is smart enough to realize when you edit a post or page and will set up a redirect if the post or page's permalink has changed.  However, when creating a new page this feature will create a redirect back to the root because the page has never existed before.  More found here (http://www.blakeimeson.com/wordpress-redirection-plugin-home-page-redirect-problem-bug/ and http://tulsawebresults.com/solution-wordpress-redirection-plugin-error ).

Comment: I tried both, but when I did as per this link http://tulsawebresults.com/solution-wordpress-redirection-plugin-error
still same thing happens, no change,
but when I tried the next link, and deleted the posts, it gets deleted, when I come back to that group, the links are still there, Its not getting deleted.

Comment: @everyone I solved this by just adding some few lines in .htaccess file, the actual reason was, sometimes server changes some mod_security.c due to which, this was happening, this blog helped me to figure it out, http://nirajmchauhan.blogspot.com/2011/01/wordpress-publish-new-post-redirecting.html