# W3 Cache redirects to front page when I press purge all caches

Tags: redirect, migration, plugin-w3-total-cache

I migrated my site to a new server. Everything seems to be fine, but the browser is redirected to the frontpage when I save configurations in either the "W3 Total Cache" plugin or in "Duplicate post" plugin.
It does save the edits, but it´s annoing with the redirect.

For example when I press purge all caches from W3 Cache, it is redirected to

```
www.mysite.com/?w3tc_note=flush_all
```

I can´t find a solution that solves it. I tried with:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

In my wp-config.php

And with these google results:
[Redirecting to home-page when saving any edited code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7993/redirecting-to-home-page-when-saving-any-edited-code)
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-5-0-beta3-redirects-to-wp-admin-edit-php-after-hitting-enter-key/

I also looked at the wp_options in the DB. But seems allright.

I tried to change the wp permanent link options in the admin settings too.

The "Duplicate post" plugin was installed after the site migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution. To anyone in the future having this problem here's what i did:

- I used the plugin "Duplicator" and made a package of the site.
- Then i downloaded the installer and the archive.
- I then deleted everything in the database and on the ftp.
- Then I transfered the archive and installer file to the FTP and run
  the installer.php

Now everything works again :)

Answer (score 2):

It's because you have set the Referrer Policy header incorrectly set in the W3TC page cache.

```
Referrer Policy
This header restricts the values of the referer header in outbound links.
**Directive: same-origin**
```

...will fix it. If your overall Directive is "same-origin" and you set the Referrer header to something different (such as "origin"), this error will occur. I changed mine to same-origin and the problem was immediately fixed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll remember that!!

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to really know what is going on.  But a best "guess" is that you have a plugin that is redirecting and/or conflicting with the theme.  By process of elimination, I would deactivate all the plugins and see if the problem still exists.  If it disappears, reactivate, one by one.  Somewhere there is a conflict and doing a redirect.

A secondary effort would be, after all the plugins have been disabled and assuming it still exists, then change themes.

You have to narrow this down to the most basic element.

Comment: Thanks! But after deactivating all plugins and switching to one of the twenty theme + deleting cookies, it still does the redirecting error :(

Comment: then I would be looking at some malware or changes to functions.php.  Something is causes the redirect.

Comment: Thanks! I can´t see anything in the functions should be wrong though. And nothing else seems to be wrong. I also tried to look through the DB for any hardcoded URLs